# Unprotect all sheets in all binary workbooks in a folder and save them unprotected

Tags: r, excel, vba, password-protection

- I have a folder with *.xlsb* workbooks.
- Each workbooks has 5 sheets, all of them protected with a password.
- The password is common for all sheets, for all workbooks.
- The workbooks themselves have no password.

How can I unprotect all the sheets of all the workbooks and saved them as unprotected?

I found the following code but it fails to do what I need (it works for only the active workbook).

```
Sub unprotect_all_sheets() 
On Error Goto booboo 
unpass = InputBox("password") 
For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
Worksheet.Unprotect Password:=unpass
Next
Exit Sub
booboo: MsgBox "There is s problem - check your password, capslock, etc."
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996740/import-password-protected-xlsx-workbook-into-r

Comment: In R you could use `xl.read.file` from `excel.link`, for reading password-protected spreadsheets.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233738/how-to-read-an-xls-file-that-is-encrypted-with-r

Comment: @Brad Your link is about protecting, not UNprotecting. Please withdraw the duplicate sign.

Comment: @SamFirke the `excel.link` does not work with .xlsb

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Sounds like you just found code on the internet, it didn't work, so came asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

Any fails to unprotect the sheets are reported in the immediate window

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFol As String
    Dim strPass As String

    'password
    strPass = "tested"

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    'folder to work in
    strFol = "c:\temp\"

    StrFile = Dir(strFol & "*.xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(strFol & StrFile)
            For Each ws In Wb.Worksheets
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Unprotect strPass
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print strFol & StrFile & " " & ws.Name
            On Error GoTo 0

        Next
        Wb.Save
        Wb.Close
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

     With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```